# gitignoring a particular folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to use a .gitignore file to ignore a top level /assets directory, so my file says:

assets/

This is working - however other folders at lower levels of my app are also getting ignores - any folder called assets is being ignored.  eg. /style/img/assets.

So how to I specify I only want the /assets directory at the top level to be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore just the root folder try:

```
/assets/
```